# upgrade / remove yp server host - who is connected

Tags: yp

Is it possible to find out which hosts are using a yp server? I want to remove / update an older VM that's acting as a yp-server but it's not clear which clients are out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is: `ypserv` normally only logs errors into the syslog. This isn't helpful for your use case.

Workaround, assuming RHEL/CentOS, other systems should be similar.

- Check if `/etc/ypserv.securenets` exists and is of any help. This *can* include a line for every host allowed to use NIS.
- Put `ypserv` into debug mode with the `-d` option. This should spew out a line for every connection to STDERR. See `man ypserv`. Warning: `ypserv` will not background itself in this mode. Run it in `screen` or similar.
- The evil way: Prevent all connections in `/etc/ypserv.securenets` and look into `/var/log/messages` to see who wanted to connect :)

Comment: Yow. Sounds a bit draconian. I like it. "Pinch the air hose and see who turns blue."

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/336240/how-can-i-tell-which-clients-are-connecting-to-a-nis-ypserv-master-server?rq=1